# which data structure to use for specific text editor

Tags: optimization, data-structures

Some text editor needs to perform the following operations:

- insert one character
- delete one character

Linked list example:

```
Insert(3,"x"):

   before:  [a]-[b]-[c]-[d]-...
   after:   [a]-[b]-[x]-[c]-[d]-...

Delete(3):

   before:  [a]-[b]-[x]-[c]-[d]-...
   after:   [a]-[b]-[c]-[d]-...
```

Which would be the optimal data structure to implement this behavior? (my gut feeling: red-black tree)

Comment: If by optimal you mean smallest Big O bound any tree structure would be better than a LinkedList, O(n) vs. O(log(n)). This includes searching for the character and deleting it. If the time it will take to write the program is a big factor than the LinkedList will be the optimal solution assuming you are writing those data structures from scratch.

Comment: Yes, I mean optimal algorithm complexity, i.e. smallest big-O bound for worst case. Note that the Delete and Insert operations are done according to an offset from the beginning of the data, not by searching for a character. So the data structure must keep track of the position of each character, and allow for an efficient algorithm to find the k-th element. The linked list was just an example to illustrate the functionality, I expect that this can be done faster with some other data structure.